# How to use Abel's criterion for convergence of $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}+\cos(x)} \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

In my homework we are supposed to show that the integral $\displaystyle\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}+\cos(x)} \mathrm dx$ converges, using Abel's criterion. There should not be any deep result or manipulation needed.

Of course the obvious idea of writing the integrand as $\sin(x)\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\cos(x)}$ does not work since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\cos(x)}$ does not *decrease* towards $0$.

Instead I thought that I could write it as $\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and show that $\displaystyle\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}}\mathrm dx$ is bounded. It seemed reasonable since $\frac{1}{1+\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}}$ converges to $1$ as $x\to \infty$, so it should not add too much perturbation to the boundedness of the integral of $\sin(x)$. But this is like saying that the equivalence of functions preserves the boundedness of the integral, which is only true for *positive* functions. And indeed if I try to prove it by hand, I realize that the fact that $\sin(x)$ changes sign prevents me from writing a good estimation to show boundedness.

Am I missing something? Should I consider a different application of Abel's criterion?

Comment: I have a feeling there is a "clever" answer.

Comment: @AdamRubinson  It's easy to show convergence using comparison test, but OP is asking about Abel's criterion

Comment: @SineoftheTime I know. What I meant was, I have a feeling there is a clever answer using Abel's test.

Comment: @SineoftheTime Honestly if there is a simple proof, even not using Abel, I'd be happy to see it, I'm getting discouraged, I tried many things but did not really get anywhere.

Comment: @EagerStudent do you know asymptotic behaviour?

Comment: Yes, but our teacher said that those comparison theorems only work for positive functions (and he explained why, it made sense), so I did not see how to apply them here.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks. The final remark you were referring to is wrong. I will remove it.  Especially that it is contradictory to my answer to this question.

Comment: @EagerStudent when your teacher/professor tells you the answer, please can you post it on here? I'm curious what the answer is.

Answer (score 2):

We will use the Dirichlet test which implies the convergence of  the integrals $$\int\limits_1^\infty{\sin(ax)\over x^b}\,dx, \quad b>0$$ We have $${\sin x\over \sqrt{x}+\cos x}-{\sin x \over \sqrt{x}}={\cos x\sin x \over (\sqrt{x}+\cos x)\sqrt{x}}\\ ={1\over 2}{\sin(2x)\over x+\sqrt{x}\cos x}$$ It suffices to show that the integral of the last expression is convergent. We have $${\sin(2x)\over x+\sqrt{x}\cos x}-{\sin(2x)\over x}={\cos x\sin(2x)\over x(\sqrt{x}+\cos x)}
$$ The obtained function is absolutely integrable. Hence the original integral is convergent.

Comment: Ok, but this is Dirichlet's test and not Abel's test, as requested.

Comment: @AdamRubinson It's hard to apply the Abel test, which actually is a consequence of the Dirichlet test. For example how do you prove that the integral of $(\sin x)/x$ is convergent basing on the Abel test ?

Comment: I agree with you it's hard, but maybe there is another way. Maybe OP's lecturer had something else in mind?